# Can Random Sampling Help Improve Data Quality Problems?

Tags: sampling

I am working with a hospital dataset.

Patients come in and provide information (i.e. var1, var2, var3) about themselves and their partner (if they have one). Later, their partner also come and provide the same information about themselves and their partner that just came in.

The dataset looks something like this:

```
| patient | patient_partner | patient_var1 | patient_var2 | patient_var3 | patient_partner_var1 | patient_partner_var2 | patient_partner_var3 |
|---------|-----------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| john    | sally           | 1            | 5            | 7            | 1                    | 5                    | 7                    |
| sally   | john            | 1            | 5            | 7            | 1                    | 5                    | 7                    |
| kevin   | NULL            | 7            | 1            | 0            | NULL                 | NULL                 | NULL                 |
| tim     | lucy            | 9            | 6            | 1            | 5                    | 4                    | 1                    |
| lucy    | tim             | 5            | 4            | 1            | 9                    | 6                    | 1                    |
| jane    | jack            | 1            | 2            | 2            | 9                    | 6                    | 2                    |
| jack    | jane            | 5            | 2            | 2            | 1                    | 2                    | 2                    |
```

As  we can see:

- sometimes a patient has no partner (e.g. kevin)
- sometimes the patient and their partner have exactly the same information and both will give the exact same information about each other (e.g. john and sally)
- sometimes the patient and their partner have different information and both will still give the same information about each other (e.g. tim and lucy)
- sometimes the information provided by the patient about their partner does not exactly match the information that their partner directly provided. (e.g. jack and jane)

There could be many reasons why this is (e.g. data quality errors, miscommunication, the information could have changed during the time that the first partner provided the information, the information could actually be different e.g. the patient and the partner have 2 kids together but the partner also has a kid from a previous marriage, etc.).

It is also possible that Jack can provide more accurate information about Jane compared to the information that Jane provides about herself.

The goal is to estimate the average values of var1, var2, var3 in this dataset.

Ideally, I would have de-duplicated the dataset and kept one row of data for each couple- however, in this case it is not possible as I am not sure which row to keep and discard. If I keep both rows, I risk overestimating/underestimating the average value of var1,var2, var3. If I remove one row, I also risk overestimating/underestimating the average value of var1,var2, var3.

Here is the idea I came up with:

- Suppose I assume data quality issues are randomly distributed
- Then, perhaps only using the patient_var1, patient_var2 and patient_var3 columns on the original dataset (i.e. no de-duplication), I can randomly sample rows with replacement (e.g. 5% of the rows) and calculate the average values of patient_var1, patient_var2 and patient_var3.
- I can repeat this random sampling process and averaging many times to get a distribution of var1, var2, var3. Then, I can take the average value of each distribution to get the final average of var1, var2, var3.
- By doing this, I think I will have indirectly guarded against data inconsistency issues and have gotten a general sense of the average values of var1, var2, var3

Is this a statistically valid idea?

Comment: Do you even know, whether some data would be overpresented if you take the whole data set? i would do the calculations three times: 1) all data 2) data with one of the partners and all singles 3) data with the other half and all singles. Only if you see meaningful differences between the 3 calculations, sampling makes sense

Comment: can you elaborate on this please

Comment: Consider the two cases where the patient and their partner have exact or different information but both end up giving the exact same information about each other (e.g. john and sally + tim and lucy), in this case i think there's redundancy, so only one line of information should be kept.

Comment: For **all** the couples (if they have one) do they both provide information in the *patient_var1*, *patient_var2* and *patient_var3* columns ? If the answer is yes, then there's no loss of information by disregarding the variables *patient_partner_var1*, *patient_partner_var2* and *patient_partner_var3*

Comment: thanks ... but what about for couples like jack and jane? can random sampling help here?

Comment: @ Galen: thank you for the edits ... but I think you accidentally changed the table I was using... certain values are now missing... I will try to re-edit it

Comment: Random sampling can only lose information.

Comment: But if some data is good and some is bad (as in this example)... if losing information is done correctly via random sampling and you lose some of the bad data... isn't that a good thing? I.e. improve estimation

Comment: "The goal is to estimate the average values of var1, var2, var3 in this dataset.". What do you intend to do with this estimation? I ask, because it might be relevant to know if you want to use the information to predict an outcome you don't mention in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Samples will inherit the properties of the population that you sample from. If  the population has data quality problems, then so will the sample.

Since you already know the nature of your data quality issues, one solution will be to identify and treat these by designing specific fixes for each type of issue. You could do this multiple times with multiple approaches and that will give you a range of values to help you understand the margin of error.