# Why is an offset needed in Poisson Regression?

Tags: regression, poisson-regression, offset

Why does Poisson Regression require an offset variable when we model rates instead of a count?

In a Poisson Distribution, lambda itself is a rate (e.g. cars per minute). It seems like the Poisson Regression should be naturally able to handle rates since its based on the Poisson Distribution which itself is based on a rate.

So why can't I just use the basic Poisson Regression and replace the count variable with the equivalent rate? Is there some special reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'modelling rates instead of a count'?

Comment: Rate=Count/Exposure @GeorgeSavva

Comment: You can also directly model rates, using the exposure as weight. The model coefficients will be identical to a model of with log(Exposure) as offset.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda is the **average number of events in a fixed interval** (time or space). For example the distribution of chewing gums on each tile on the sidewalk - shamelessly stolen from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) ;)

[image]

Now what would you do when the tiles were different sizes (as some of them are in this snapshot)? You can associate your counts to a **varying** interval size via the offset specification. So the offset adjust your counts when the interval associated with your counts changes over your experiment.

Comment: thank you for this cool example! but why cant I just replace the count response variable with a rate variable and carry on anyways?

Comment: @pq44pq Consider 100 pieces of gum in 100 square meters of pavement vs 1 piece of gum on 1 square meter.  These are the same rate but do not carry the same amount of information.

Comment: @pq44pq have a look at Gung's answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/175365/32477 or ocram's answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11183/32477 This goes into much more detail.

Comment: thanks! I will read these answers... btw do either of you have any opinions about the previous question I asked? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641228/can-random-sampling-help-improve-data-quality-problems can random sampling be useful here?